# Append multiple 'text' elements in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a graph with an element which appears on mouseover, to which there is attached a circle, text and an svg:line as follows:

```
    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .style("display", "none")

    var circleRadius = 4.5;

    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("r", circleRadius);

    focus.append("text")
        .attr("y", -9)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");

    focus.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("x2", 0) // vertical line so same value on each
        .attr("y1", circleRadius).attr("y2", 200); // top to bottom 

    /*focus.append("text")
        .attr("y", -2)
        .attr("x", -20);*/
```

I want to add a second text element (the one currently commented out) but when I try to do that it won't render the first text element. Is there a way to append multiple elements of the same type to a group? Also I need to be able to select them independently (as shown below, I have two focus.select('text') functions, one for each text element, and currently I can't distinguish them).

Secondary question; the second text element is showing a time string in full format (e.g. Thu Jun 26 2014 08:30:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Standard Time)). Can I format this on the fly to get just the hour/minute/seconds? Currently the text elements get data from this code:

```
        focus.select("text")
            .text(d.temperature)
            .attr("font-family", "NorWester")
            .attr("font-size", 11);
        focus.select("text")
            .text(d.time)
            .attr("y", function() { return (height - y(d.temperature)) })
            .attr("font-family", "NorWester")
            .attr("font-size", 11);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What SVG element is focus? I think it must be a `g` to work with multiple `text` elements.

For the formatting, d3 has a neat function:

```
var format = d3.time.format('%H:%M');
// ...
focus.select('text').text(function(d) {return format(d.time);});
```

Edit: Working jsfiddle demo, showing two texts elements inside a group:
[jsfiddle.net/PRvGC/](http://jsfiddle.net/PRvGC/)

Comment: Sorry, yes, focus is a group element.

Comment: Also I looked at the fiddle and it doesn't fix my problem. I have two focus.select('text') items in a mousemove function, and one has to select the top text element, while the second must select the bottom text element. Is there a way to distinguish between them?

Comment: Use classes or ids to distinguish between the two text elements. [extended demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRvGC/1/)

Comment: Why not assign each of them a class, like: `.attr('class', 'top-text')` for the top and `.attr('class', 'bottom-text')` for the bottom.

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. Thanks to both of you. As a quick aside, anyone know a good d3 zoom tutorial? It's a bit of a tricky concept to grasp, how to zoom into a graph...

Comment: It was the `.attr('y', 12)` that helped me here. I figured on the `g` aspect, but the lines were overwriting each other. Had to account for this in the `y` attr. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently when I wanted to create 4 rectangles with different properties.  I solved this with HTML ids and selectAll.  Here is an example:

```
var van = road.selectAll('#van').data([5]).enter() 
.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d) { return 300})
.attr('y', function(d) { return 100})
.attr('width', 30)
.attr('height', 15)
.style('fill', 'brown');
```

Time formatting in D3:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: Why `selectAll` on a unique id? It's just a very detail, but when i read selectAll i expect multiple elements in the resulting selection.

Comment: Yes, it will work in this case with select or selectAll since there is only one id of van.  Select would probably look cleaner.